# Rails - javascript not reloading divs via remote call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to create a timeline where a user can create events to go on the timeline. I've had this working fine in the past, but have since updated my version of Rails to 3.2.14, and it no longer works. Could this possibly be a syntactical error if something has changed between versions, or have I done something wrong?

The timeline show view renders partials including the timeline, and create/edit/destroy form partials for the events. As I understand it, the form is getting submitted, and should be calling create.js.erb.

What is actually happening is that when I click 'create event', the contents of the page are simply replaced by the standard "Event was successfully created" notice (not the one from the create.js.erb), and everything else disappears. The event has been created though. Can anyone help?

timeline show view:

```
<div id="show-timeline">
<%= render :partial => "show_timeline" %>
</div>

<div class="content-box timeline-box">
    <div id="my-timeline-box">
        <%= render :partial => "my_timeline" %>
    </div>
<br />

<button id="new-event-button" class="btn btn-success btn-large">New Event</button>
<button id="edit-events-button" class="btn btn-info btn-large">Edit Events</button>
<button id="delete-events-button" class="btn btn-danger btn-large">Delete Events</button>

<div id="events-forms">
    <div id="new-event">
        <%= render :partial => "new_event", :locals => { :event => Event.new(:timeline_id=>@timeline.id) }, :remote => true %>
    </div>

    <div id="edit-events">
        <%= render :partial => "edit_events", :locals => { :events => current_user.events }, :remote => true %> 
    </div>

    <div id="delete_events">
        <%= render :partial => "delete_events", :locals => { :events => current_user.events } %>        
    </div>
</div>
<div id="events-forms-edit">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

events/create.js.erb

```
$('#new-event').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/new_event", :locals => { :event => Event.new(:timeline_id=>@timeline.id) }, :remote => true ) %>');
$('.notice').html("<p>Event was successfully created.</p>");
$('.notice').show(300);
$('#my-timeline-box').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/my_timeline" ) %>');
$('#show-timeline').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/show_timeline" ) %>');
$('#edit-events').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/edit_events", :locals => { :events => current_user.events }, :remote => true ) %>');
$('#delete_events').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "/timelines/delete_events", :locals => { :events => current_user.events } ) %>');
```

events controller create action:

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    @timeline = current_user.timeline

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event.timeline, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Update:

_new_event.html.erb

```
<br />
<h2>Add an event</h2>
<h4>Fill in the form and click 'Create Event' to add a new event to the timeline.</h4>

<%= form_for(event, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <% if event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <%=f.hidden_field 'timeline_id', :value => current_user.timeline.id %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :start_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :start_year => 1800 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :headline, :size => 50 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :event_description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :text, :size => "47x4" %>
  </div>
  <%= check_box_tag "blockCheck", :value => "1", :checked => false %>
  <div class="field" id="media_box">
    <%= f.label :media %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Please paste a URL here</span><br />
    <%= f.text_field :media, :size => 50 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :media_description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :caption, :size => "47x3" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Create Event', :class => "btn btn-success"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

console output (when "Create Event" is clicked):

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-07 15:07:03 +0100
Processing by EventsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"ppQnTSwha1veoTzAenrtl7uhtQ8wC
F6c2/AZMDGA/UE=", "event"=>{"timeline_id"=>"4", "start_date(3i)"=>"7", "start_da
te(2i)"=>"8", "start_date(1i)"=>"2013", "headline"=>"", "text"=>"", "media"=>"",
 "caption"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (5.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users
"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mTimeline Load (15.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "timelines".* FROM "timelines" WHE
RE "timelines"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mTimeline Load (38.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "timelines".* FROM "timelines"
 WHERE "timelines"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (6.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO "events" ("caption", "created_at", "
credit", "end_date", "headline", "media", "start_date", "text", "thumbnail", "ti
meline_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)←[0m  [["capti
on", ""], ["created_at", Wed, 07 Aug 2013 14:07:04 UTC +00:00], ["credit", nil],
 ["end_date", nil], ["headline", ""], ["media", ""], ["start_date", Wed, 07 Aug
2013], ["text", ""], ["thumbnail", nil], ["timeline_id", 4], ["updated_at", Wed,
 07 Aug 2013 14:07:04 UTC +00:00]]
  ←[1m←[35m (171.0ms)←[0m  commit transaction
  Rendered timelines/_new_event.html.erb (15.0ms)
  Rendered timelines/_my_timeline.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered timelines/_show_timeline.html.erb (0.0ms)
  ←[1m←[36mEvent Load (30.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JO
IN "timelines" ON "events"."timeline_id" = "timelines"."id" WHERE "timelines"."u
ser_id" = 2←[0m
  Rendered timelines/_edit_events.html.erb (41.0ms)
  Rendered timelines/_delete_events.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered events/create.js.erb (5123.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7899ms (Views: 7538.4ms | ActiveRecord: 265.0ms)
```

However, nothing is getting rendered.

Comment: can i see the _new_event.html.erb partial

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of the original question now. Thanks

Comment: Whats the output on your firebug console?

Comment: Added the console output as well.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9972/beck03076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have the following lines in the top of your **application.js.coffee**:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
```

If you're not using coffee, the lines should be the same but starting with `//=`.

It seems like you're not requiring Rails Unobtrusive Javascript library, so your form post is treated as HTML instead of JS.

If you do have this dependency covered, could you also provide the code for the javascript files related to this issue?

Comment: Yes, I do have those lines in application.js - which js files do you need to see? thanks

Comment: First of all, I'd need the firebug console "RESPONSE" for the create event action. You should select the POST in the console and click the tab "Response" to see it.

Comment: The output from the console when the 'create event' button is clicked has been added to the original question. I don't have a 'response' tab in my console, sorry.

Comment: I've added the javascript_include defaults on the application layout just to be sure, but still no different. Is there any way it could be skipping the requirement?